# Upload image with ModelAttribute Liferay

Tags: spring-mvc, upload, liferay

I would like to send a form to update my user, the form contains a modelAttribute and an image to upload.

If i use the enctype="multipart/form-data" the image is uploaded but all the fields in modelAttribute are null.

If i remove the enctype="multipart/form-data" my modelAttribute is correctly filled but the image is not uploaded...

Do you have a solution?

My code below :

The jsp :

```
<portlet:actionURL name="submitMyInfosForm" var="submitMyInfosFormUrl">
     <portlet:param name="submitMyInfosForm" value="submitMyInfosForm"/>
</portlet:actionURL>

<form:form class="fm" modelAttribute="myInfosForm" action='${actionFormUrl}' enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post" id='myInfosForm'>      
                    <div class="fm_c">      
                        <label class="fm_c_n">
                            <p><spring:message code="portlet.moncompte.infos.form.firstname"/></p>
                            <input type="text" name="firstName" value="${myInfosForm.firstName}" <c:if test="${not isUpdateInfos}"> class="disabled" disabled</c:if> />
                            <div id="error_infos_firstName" class="error"></div>
                        </label>

                        <label class="fm_c_n">
                            <p><spring:message code="portlet.moncompte.infos.form.lastname"/></p>
                            <input type="text" name="lastName" value="${myInfosForm.lastName}" <c:if test="${not isUpdateInfos}"> class="disabled" disabled</c:if> />
                            <div id="error_infos_lastName" class="error"></div>
                        </label>

                        <label class="fm_c_n">
                            <p><spring:message code="portlet.moncompte.infos.form.email"/></p>
                            <input type="text" name="emailAddress" value="${myInfosForm.emailAddress}" <c:if test="${not isUpdateInfos}"> class="disabled" disabled</c:if> />
                             <div id="error_infos_emailAddress" class="error"></div>
                        </label>

                        <label class="fm_c_n">
                            <p><spring:message code="portlet.moncompte.infos.form.phone"/></p>
                            <input type="text" name="phone" value="${myInfosForm.phone}" <c:if test="${not isUpdateInfos}"> class="disabled" disabled</c:if> />
                            <div id="error_infos_phone" class="error"></div>
                        </label>

                        <label class="fm_c_n">
                            <p class="fm_c_n add"><spring:message code="portlet.moncompte.infos.form.address"/></p>
                            <div class="fm_c_n address">
                                <div id="error_infos_street1" class="error"></div>
                                <input type="text" name="street1" value="${myInfosForm.street1}" <c:if test="${not isUpdateInfos}"> class="disabled" disabled</c:if> />
                                <div id="error_infos_street2" class="error"></div>
                                <input type="text" name="street2" value="${myInfosForm.street2}" <c:if test="${not isUpdateInfos}"> class="disabled" disabled</c:if> />
                            </div>
                        </label>

                        <label class="fm_c_n">
                            <p><spring:message code="portlet.moncompte.infos.form.postalCode"/></p>
                            <input type="text" name="zip" value="${myInfosForm.zip}" <c:if test="${not isUpdateInfos}"> class="disabled" disabled</c:if> />
                            <div id="error_infos_zip" class="error"></div>
                        </label>

                        <label class="fm_c_n">
                            <p><spring:message code="portlet.moncompte.infos.form.city"/></p>
                            <input type="text" name="city" value="${myInfosForm.city}" <c:if test="${not isUpdateInfos}"> class="disabled" disabled</c:if> />
                            <div id="error_infos_city" class="error"></div>
                        </label>
                    </div>
                    <aside class="fm_photo">
                        <label class="fm_n">
                                    <p><spring:message code="portlet.moncompte.infos.form.portrait"/></p>
                                    <div id="error_infos_portrait" class="error"></div>
                                    <input name="portrait" size="50" type="file" />
                        </label>
                        <!-- p>
                            <img alt="<%=HtmlUtil.escape(currentUser.getFullName()) %>" class="user-logo" src="<%= currentUser.getPortraitURL(themeDisplay) %>" />
                        </p -->
                        <img src="<%= currentUser.getPortraitURL(themeDisplay) %>" alt="<%=HtmlUtil.escape(currentUser.getFullName()) %>" />
                    </aside>
                    </form:form>
```

The controller :

```
 @ActionMapping(params = "javax.portlet.action=submitMyInfosForm")
    public void updateMyInfos(@ModelAttribute MyInfosForm infosForm, ActionRequest request, ActionResponse response,
            Model model) {
```

The modelAttribute :

```
public class MyInfosForm {

    private String firstName;

    private String lastName;

    private String emailAddress;

    private String phone;

    private String street1;

    private String street2;

    private String zip;

    private String city;

    private MultipartFile portrait;
...
}
```

Thanks in advance for your help

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `UploadPortletRequest` instead of `ActionRequest` while using `enctype="multipart/form-data"`

I am not familiar with Spring Framework but you can get `UploadPortletRequest` from `ActionRequest` using ,

```
UploadPortletRequest uploadRequest = PortalUtil.getUploadPortletRequest(actionRequest);
```

And you can fetch the content and using it ,

```
File file = uploadRequest.getFile("fileName");
String someData = ParamUtil.getString(uploadRequest, "someData");
```